# batch file to copy newest backup file

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2, copy

I've currently got a SQL job (SQL Server 2008 R2) that checks all the backup files in a folder and then dynamically creates a batch file to copy the most recent on to a new location with a new name so that it can be compressed will other backup files.

I'm looking to turn this into a batch file on it's own without the need to run the SQL Server part first.  But can't work out how to find out the most recent backup file.  Some checking online has shown how to get the most recent file in a folder, but there are transaction log backups in the same folder.

Basically I thought it would be something like:

```
for /f %%x in ('dir "J:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\CommonInterface\*.bak" /B /O:-D') do set NEWEST_BAK & goto DONE

:DONE
copy "%newest%" F:\backup\new.bak
Pause
```

but that gives the error:

```
Environment variable NEWEST_BAK not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are thousands of files then this doesn't need the break from the loop.

```
@echo off
pushd "J:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\CommonInterface"
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir "*.bak" /B /O:D') do set "NEWEST_BAK=%%x"
copy "%newest_bak%" "F:\backup\new.bak"
popd
Pause
```

The transaction log backups will have to either be excluded and we need to know the naming scheme, or if the most recent file is always what you need then the above will work.

Comment: That worked great! the transaction logs don't have a .bak extension.  Thanks for your help and the quick reply